# Boot Repair - 'Close all package managers...' Dual Boot Installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, package-management, windows-8, boot-repair

After almost a week, I've just about managed to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS alongside Windows 8 on a Dell XPS 14 Ultrabook.

I have created a partition in Windows to store Ubuntu, rebooted from Windows Advanced Start Up options menu to an EFI USB containing Ubuntu.
I've installed Ubuntu on my chosen partition with 4GB swap area also set aside.

During the install, I get this error message:

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will no boot.
```

After some searching, I read that I should use Boot-Repair, which I've done following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

However, after running Boot-Repair and choosing the auto diagnose and repair option, I get a message to,

```
Please close all your package managers (Software Center, Update Manager, Synaptic, ...) Then try again.
```

Can someone please help me with what I need to do next as it's driving me mad?

Ubuntu is installed (if i try to reinstall on the same partition, my previous installation is there), it just seems I need to fix this problem.

Please help - Windows 8 is awful but I'm getting very tired of the endless pushing a big rock up a steep hill that installing Ubuntu is.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Comment: @lovinbuntu there is no boot-info url when you get this error. the process aborts before it generates one.

Comment: correct, but then you can click the "Create BootInfo" button so it generates an URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the update manager is checking for update in background. Go to 'about this system' and then click install updates.
After the check was complete just click remind me later. Then you can use boot repair. It will not show that error message after that